# Rename Description tab in Woocommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, product

I pasted this code in function.php, but it didn't rename the product page tab as it supposed to (http://www.noushasasart.com/product/harsh-bark/)

```
function woo_remove_product_tabs($tabs) {
    unset($tabs['reviews']);    // Remove the reviews tab
    $tabs['description']['title'] = __('Additional Information');  // Rename the 

    description tab        
    return $tabs;
}
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have forgotten the filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_customize_tabs', 100, 1 );
function woo_customize_tabs( $tabs ) {

    unset($tabs['reviews']);    // Remove the reviews tab

    $tabs['description']['title'] = __( 'More Information' ); // Rename the description tab

    return $tabs;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

---

**Update *(related to your comment)*** | Rename product description heading (inside the tab):

To rename description heading use **`woocommerce_product_description_heading`** filter hook this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_description_heading', 'rename_product_description_heading', 10, 1 );
function rename_product_description_heading( $heading ) {
    return  __( 'Additional Information', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

---

Official related documentation: [Editing product data tabs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/)

Comment: I replaced in function.php file which is in this location[/public_html/wp-includes]. This is the only place I have to add this snippet right? 

but it didn't work,

note: im using a theme purchased from envato

Comment: I pasted in the currently active theme folder/function.php, but I don't see any difference in the page, Just wondering 
(http://www.noushasasart.com/product/harsh-bark/)

this theme doesn't have tabs like other woocommerce pages. Does it matter?

Comment: @LoiTheAztec,
Hi, thank you for taking me along.
I added CSS: 
'display: none;' in somewhere to hide the tab completely.
Now I think your PHP snippet works but the tab is hidden.

The content under "description" heading comes from woo-product page default editor. Hope I make sense

Here I share a screenshot and what I'm trying to achieve here is, change the heading of this "Description"

 [https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CSvX.png]

Comment: Your updated code works so perfect, Thank you millions